# Multiple touches on screen causes fps drop

Tags: ios, swift, skspritenode, frame-rate

I am trying to write a game in swift with spritesnode.
I used the "touchesBegan" to shoot enemies and "touchesMoved" to move my ship. After a short minutes, the fps fall from 60 to almost 0 while the memory remains low (30 MB) and CPU is 100% almost all the time. I have about 30 nodes, 15 Draws.
Here is the code of the "shooting"

```
func fire() {

    laser = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Laser")
    laser.name = "Laser"
    laser.size = CGSize(width: 20, height: 2)
    laser.position = ship.position

    if vitesse < 0 {
        let moveX = SKAction.moveBy (x: WidthScreen-ship.position.x, y: 0, duration: 0.5)
        let moveXDone = SKAction.removeFromParent()
        laser.run(SKAction.sequence([moveX, moveXDone]))
    } else {
        let moveX = SKAction.moveBy(x: -WidthScreen+ship.position.x, y: 0, duration: 0.5)
        let moveXDone = SKAction.removeFromParent()
        laser.run(SKAction.sequence([moveX, moveXDone]))
    }

    laser.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: (laser.size))
    laser.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Laser
    laser.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Invaders | PhysicsCategory.SmartInvaders | PhysicsCategory.UfoToSmart
    laser.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    laser.zPosition = 3

    let soundAction = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("Laser.wav", waitForCompletion: true);
    self.run(soundAction)

    self.addChild(laser)
}
```

and the code of the TouchesAction

```
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch : UITouch = touches.first!
    var touchLocation = touch.location(in: self)
    if touchLocation.y > 88*HeightScreen/100 {
        touchLocation.y = 88*HeightScreen/100
    }
    if touchLocation.y < HeightScreen/15 {
        touchLocation.y = HeightScreen/15
    }
    elevation = touchLocation.y
}


override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
   /* Called when a touch begins */
    if lifeArray.count>0{
        fire()
    }
}
```

Someone would have an idea where the probleme come from ?
Thank for your help

Sincerely

[Here image of CPU instruments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzjMo.png)

Comment: Profile it in instruments.

Comment: Hi, i put an image of CPU recording. If someone can explain to me ... Thank  you

Comment: Nobody have an idea ?